# How to call java from C++

Tags: java, c++, jar

I need to run this line from my c++ program:

java -jar test.jar text1 text2

the java app will give a float value and give it to the c++ program.

How can I do this? I never call a java stuff before from my ms visual studio C++ file.

Comment: How come you don't accept answers on any of your questions?

Comment: i don't know that i need to accept the answers. by the way, how to accept?

Comment: looks like he "accepted" his own "answer", which is another question >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the java command directly on my command prompt, it works. but when I run the command from the c++ file, the error says "The system cannot execute the specified program" .

here's my code, im using ms visual studio 2005 :

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <conio.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    float value;

    FILE  *child = _popen("java -jar c:\simmetrics_jar_v1_6_2_d07_02_07.jar text1 ssdyr445", "r");
    if (fscanf(child, "%f", &value) == 1)
         {
            fprintf(stdout,"Got Value from simmetrics: %f\n", value);
     }
    else
         {
            fprintf(stdout,"ERROR\n");
         }
    fclose(child);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want strong coupling use [JNI wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use popen() and pclose().

The function popen(), forks() and execs() a sub processes. But it attaches the sub-processes standard-in and standard-out the stream object created by popen. Thus writting anything to the stream in the parent sends it to the standard-in of the sub-processes while anything the sub-processes writes to standard-out can be read from the stream by the parent:

```
double value;
FILE*  child = popen("java -jar test.jar text1 text2", "r");
if (fscanf(child, "%f", &value) == 1)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"Got Value: %f\n", value);
}
else
{
    fprintf(stdout,"ERROR\n");
}
fclose(child);
```

Comment: i tried the code, but still doesn't work. It somehow does not pass the float value from the jar application.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;


int main()
{

float value;


FILE*  child = popen("java -jar simmetrics_jar_v1_6_2_d07_02_07.jar text1 aab676788", "r");

fscanf(child,"%f",&value);
fprintf(stdout,"Got Value from simmetrics: %f\n", value);



fclose(child);



return 0;
}

Comment: Did you check the result of popen? If it fails to start the java VM or fails to find the jar file then it will generate an error.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest if You can modify your java code:

write the result to environment variable (pseudo code below):

solution 1. 
(Write directly to env. in java app.)

java:

```
...
setenv('ret', somefloatvalue);
...

exit..
```

c++:

```
system("java -jar test.jar text1 text2")
...
getenv("ret")
```

(I haven't test it, but important here is the context, does system creates another shell (console),
if yes, you'll not see those envs, therefore some other spawn method is necessary)

**CreateProcess()** on windows
**fork()** on linux.

There are also more complex solutions,

- send some JASON's through the sockets.... etc.
- Write to text file in java, read in
  c++.
- MPI...
- extreme in this case CORBA ;)

Comment: That will not work. When System spins up it creates its own environment for the application to run in (A copy of the c++ parents envronment). When the Java application modifies the environment it is modifying its own environment (not its parents). Thus the parent will never see the chnages.