# How to call Java from C++ and how to edit clipboard

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, clipboard

I have been trying to look for ways to run a .jar file from C++. I am doing this because I do not yet know how to add text to the Clipboard in Windows.

As an alternative, I was going to have the C++ program write the string (which is a URL, in case you are curious) to a text file and then open the .jar file which will just open the file, take the String in, close the file, and display the String in GUI format (most likely, a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`).

So far I have read

- [How to call java from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583501/how-to-call-java-from-c)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=VS.80%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0k9bb.aspx

Upon trying to go to the first site, I sort of get what they are trying to do; I try it myself, and it doesn't throw error, but the suggestion

`_popen("java -jar LinuxTest.jar", r) == 0)`

Doesn't seem to be opening `LinuxTest.jar` (which works and simply prints a OS-dependent String)!

I also tried, from the third element, `_execl("java", "java", "-jar", "LinuxTest.jar", 0);` But this returns -1 and throws a `FileNotFound` at `errno`.

I guess I am asking for understanding of multithreading (it seems to be inevitable here; I have never learned nor used any), understanding of what they are doing in the first StackOverflow post and understanding of locking/unlocking objects. I am also asking for a little more understanding of how Clipboard works

Comment: This question is in bad need of editing. Please: format your code samples and make them somewhat complete, leave out the nonsense like the links in an array that's the result of a method call (huh?), and describe what you're actually trying to accomplish instead of the circuitous ways in which you've attempted to do so.

Comment: While it is OK to include code in your posts, please *do not* write your question in code form. That's just silly.

Comment: The example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3949730/230513) uses `JNI_CreateJavaVM`.

Comment: What are you actually asking here? Locking and unlocking objects doesn't have anything to do with writing stuff to the clipboard (not directly anyway) --- and starting another process doesn't have anything to do with multi-threading....

Comment: Also it seems like you're asking two questions, how to spawn Java as a subprocess (which will probably require more information as to what the current working directory is and where the JAR is located etc.). And how to work with a clipboard. (From where? Java/AWT, or C++/whatever. The answer depends on which C++ GUI toolkit you're using, they usually deal with clipboard access.) Those should actually be two separate questions, without conflating the issues in both.

Comment: My wild guess is that you do not have `java` on the value of `PATH` that the shell spawned by `popen()` sees. It should be `/bin/sh` and it might not be reading the config file where that's set. You might be able to test that by running `popen("echo $PATH");` This goes double for your `execl()` call since that won't even attempt to search the `PATH` to begin with, as the documentation for the [`exec*()` functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) says. You need `execlp()`. Also, what are the underscore-prefixed versions of those functions and why are you using those?

Comment: I'm also confused by the use of `LinuxTest.jar` but the mention of the Windows clipboard but eh.

Comment: I guess my explanation of the problem the first time around sucked badly. Let me rephrase it: I am writing a program that makes a URL typable on YouTube (or wherever else a direct typing of the URL is prohibited). It works by taking in the URL the user wants to post, either by them typing it or by it opening the clipboard to get it, modifying it (to make it postable), and then putting it on the clipboard. After my failure to programmatically put the modified URL onto the clipboard, I tried to scavenge the Internet to find an implementation I could fully understand. Failing that, I was just

Comment: going to make a Java program (packaged into a .jar file), which will bring up a window that has the URL and will stay up until the user closes the window. This JAR file will then be called from C++ and given the URL via a text file that C++ creates prior to calling the JAR file. Yes, I know already that, indirectly, either way will **indirectly** involve multithreading and/or object locking/unlocking. (I have seen this from some of the searching that I have done.) I want to understand FULLY what I am trying to do, before I go typing it up.

Comment: system("java -jar LinuxTest.jar");

Comment: I would do that, but system() is "evil". Read this for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/

Comment: I figured out the clipboard part; it was multithreading (slightly), and I understand most of the implementation I found prior to coming here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/14349/ . (Although I am not sure as to WHY they locked/unlocked a new object, and why I couldn't just directly write the data directly to HGLOBAL; I tried and it failed.) //I originally tried to copy the URL straight to a plain old HANDLE, but switched to HGLOBAL (obviously, they are using global memory, which I seldom use, and want to know all about).